# phantomjs: is webpage singleton?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

see code below.
I want to capture two web page.
After run this code using phantomjs, I only got one screenshot of webpage(www.baidu.com).
Is webpage in phantomjs singleton? Can I open two webpages in one phantomjs intance?

```
var webpage1 = require('webpage').create();
webpage1.onLoadFinished = function() {
    webpage1.render('1.png');
} 
webpage1.open('http://www.google.com');

var webpage2 = require('webpage').create();
webpage2.onLoadFinished = function() {
    webpage2.render('2.png');
}
webpage2.open('http://www.baidu.com');
```

**UPDATE:**
thank you @Cybermaxs
I delay the end of the script, it works. I got two screenshot.

```
var webpage1 = require('webpage').create();
webpage1.onLoadFinished = function() {
    webpage1.render('1.png');
}
webpage1.open('http://www.google.com.cn');

var webpage2 = require('webpage').create();
webpage2.onLoadFinished = function() {
    webpage2.render('2.png');
}
webpage2.open('http://www.baidu.com');

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(webpage1.url);
    console.log(webpage2.url);
    phantom.exit(0);
}, 9000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your script is that PhantomJS is async by Nature.
Your script will end before

There are many ways to solve this :

**Delay the end of the script**

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    phantom.exit(0);
},5000);
```

**Use the [waitFor example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to wait for all screen shots**

**Use a recurive approach**

```
var webpage = require('webpage').create();

webpage.open('http://www.google.com', function(status)
{
 if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        } else
        {
            webpage.render('1.png');
            webpage.open('http://www.baidu.com',function(status)
            {
             if (status !== 'success') {
                        console.log('FAIL to load the address');
                    } else
                    {
                        webpage.render('2.png');
                    }
                    phantom.exit(0);
            });
        }
        }
);
```

Fro sure, you can open two pages at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, I delay the end of the script, it works.  I have updated my question.

Comment: But i am still confused. In my origin script, I did not call phantom.exit(), so phantomjs will not exit at the end of script, phantomjs should contiune running and take screenshot of the first webpage, not only the second webpage